# Como puedo desordenar una figura

Tags: python

codigo1

```
def mostrarImagen2(imagenPath, orden):
    #llamar a dividir y mostrar segun matriz orden
    lados = len(orden[0])
    imagenDividida = dividir_imagen2(imagenPath, lados)
    img = Image.open(imagenPath, 'r')
    imgBox = img.getbbox()
    width = imgBox[2]
    height = imgBox[3]
    ladoW = width//lados
    ladoH = height//lados
    imgMixed = Image.new('RGB', (width, height), color = 'white')
    for c in range(lados):
        for r in range(lados):
            if orden[c][r] != '-':
                imgMixed.paste(imagenDividida[orden[c][r] - 1], (r*ladoW, c*ladoH))    
    return imgMixed
```

codigo2

```
import random
def generar_movidas_aleatorias(tablero, cantidad_movidas, posicion_inicial):
pos_x = random.randrange(0,2)
pos_y = random.randrange(0,2)
a_mover = pos_x, pos_y
#print("a_mover", a_mover)
while cantidad_movidas > 0:
    v_mover = mover(posicion_inicial,a_mover)
    posmov_x, posmov_y = v_mover
    
    aux = tablero_random[posmov_x][posmov_y]

    tablero_random[posmov_x][posmov_y] = tablero_random[pos_x][pos_y]
    posmov_x, posmov_y = a_mover
    tablero_random[pos_x][pos_y] = aux
   
    #print("aux", aux)
    #print("pos_x, pos_y", pos_x, pos_y)
    
    #print("nueva_tabla", tablero_random)
    cantidad_movidas -= 1
    pos_x2 = random.randrange(0,4)
    pos_y3 = random.randrange(0,4)
    posicion_inicial = pos_x2, pos_y3
contador = 0
tam = len(tablero_random)
while contador < tam:
    #print(tablero_random[contador])
    contador += 1
return (tablero_random)
```

codigo3

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

boton_desordenar = widgets.Button(description='desordenar',
                             tooltip= "Desordena la figura")

figura, posicion = generar_figura_ordenada()   
def desordenar(button):
global posicion, figura
aleatorio = random.randrange(1, 60)
tablero_desordenado = generar_movidas_aleatorias(figura, aleatorio, posicion)



#imprimir bonito

contador = 0
while contador < len(tablero_desordenado):
    print(print("{:>4}".format(tablero_desordenado[contador][0]), "{:>4}".format(tablero_desordenado[contador][1]), "{:>4}".format(tablero_desordenado[contador][2]),"{:>4}".format(tablero_desordenado[contador][3])))
    contador += 1
output = widgets.Output()
display(boton_desordenar, output)
boton_desordenar.on_click(desordenar)
```

El problemas es quel codigo de arriba me retorna una imagen con un espacio en blaco y tengo que deordenar la imagen cuando se toca el boton desordenar del codigo3
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esa es la imagen que me da el codigo1, tengo que desordenarla y ademas tengo que poner 4 botones los cuales se movera el espacio en blanco, para ordenar la imagen una vez desosrdenada.
No logro desordenar la imagen y acoplar los botones para moverla